# JavaFX 2.2 Stage always on top

Tags: java, javafx, jframe, always-on-top

I have a normal JFrame (one part of the app) and a second JavaFX window (I can't use a JFrame for the JavaFX stage). The problem is that the JavaFX window should always be on top of all other windows.

I have no idea how I should solve this problem! Any ideas?

Comment: There is [a feature request in JavaFX-Jira](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-153) for this, but unfortunately the latest comment on this issue was made in 2011.I wish things were moving faster for such a trivial-looking feature.

Comment: This guys nailed it on the head. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827599/javafx-secondary-screen-always-on-top-of-all-applications

Answer (score 36):

I know this is a old thread, but things keep on changing. Coming to JDK 8u20 is a new method `primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);`

This would be the easiest way to make a stage always on top. For early access to 8u20 visit the [website](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).

```
public class KeyholeDemo extends Application {
    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        // code omitted...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Sample code taken from this nice [writeup](http://java.dzone.com/articles/javafx-8u20-days-future-past)

Comment: This is the way and worked for me. stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL) also work at some point but the stage will be still behind the task bar.

Answer (score 14):

I  have a similar problem right now.

I use this line of code to get an always on top effect:

```
stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

It works fine for me.

Here is the [doc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html)

Comment: Thanks mate, this worked also for me. Strange method, but seems to be the only easy way. Greets

Comment: Thanks a lot ! By giving this code you saved lot of efforts !!

Answer (score 2):

Like this (I'm using Alert)

```
 Stage stage = (Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
 stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

If you want it on top always blocking other windows, just set:

```
alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no API to have JavaFX stage always on top. But you can put JavaFX scene inside JFrame by using [JFXPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html).