# Keep stage on desktop JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have made a desktop clock widget and every time I go on the desktop, the app gains focus and then loses focus but its quite annoying when the app goes to the back. Is there a way I can make the app never have focus so it doesn't do that?

[Here](https://vid.me/rARl) is what I mean if it was unclear

Comment: Doe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819194/javafx-2-2-stage-always-on-top) work?

Comment: Nope, I just did `stage.setAlwaysOnTop(false);` and it didnt help @James_D

Comment: Well, if you want it to be always on top, do you think that `stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);` might work a little better?

Comment: I said I want it to stay on the desktop and never come to the front @James_D

Comment: OK, I misunderstood "it's quite annoying when the app goes to the back". I thought you wanted to prevent it going to the back. Simply calling `stage.toBack()` doesn't work?

Comment: Nope, sorry if it was unclear. Is there a similar method to 'setAlwaysOnTop();` that would keep it at the back? @James_D